# Windows Service Ports

Tags: linux, windows, networking, port

Is there a file on Windows 2008 similar to the /etc/services file in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll combine both Sergey and Squillman's answers.

The file exists in `%SystemRoot%\System32\Drivers\etc\services`, however many applications don't bother resolving their service name to a port via the [getservbyname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738538(VS.85).aspx) API and just have their port number information hard-coded into their binaries. There seems to be less of a culture of using the `services` file on Windows than on *nix. So, you can find the file and edit it, but there's no guarantee that any particular application will use the `services` file anyway.

Comment: Ah duh. Should have thought to look there. Ty

Comment: +1 I actually forgot about that file because I have _never_ seen it used.

Answer (score 0):

No, usually port info is stored in the registry or an applications specific config file(s).

Are you looking to find what's listening on your server?

Comment: No, I was actually helping someone else with their Windows system and hoping that such a file existed that I could refer them to for "common" ports. Ty for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for %WindowsDir%\System32\drivers\etc\services ?

Comment: yep that's the one